# Cisco Unified Communications Manager 10.5.1 install on virtualbox 5.1.2r

Tags: virtualization, redhat, cisco, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I am having difficulties to install Cisco Unified Communications Manager v10.5.1 on both Virtualbox 5.1.2r and VMware player12 with the same error. I have built he  machine according to Cisco's documentation but still receiving the error

> "This hardware (or a combination thereof) is not supported by Red Hat. For more information on supported hardware, please refer to http://www.redhat.com/hardware."

I have searched for this issue on Cisco, Redhat and Centos forums and websites but could not find a solution for this issue. They all say to ignore this issue and to move on but as soon as I do that the installation gets aborted. I have also tried installing Cisco Unified Communications manager v11 and received the same error.

I was able to install it on an older physical machine with the same version of Virtualbox.

I am able to install and run other 64bit virtual machines without a problem so I I don't think related to bios issue.

> Host pc
>
> ```
>       Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
>   CPU
>       Intel Xeon v4 @ 3.50GHz 37 °C
>       Broadwell-E/EP 14nm Technology
>   RAM
>       32.0GB Unknown @ 1064MHz (15-15-15-36)
>   Motherboard
>       Hewlett-Packard 212B (CPU0)
>   Graphics
>       HP Z24i (1920x1200@59Hz)
>       HP Z24i (1920x1200@59Hz)
>       1023MB NVIDIA NVS 310 (HP)  45 °C
>   Storage
>       931GB ATA ST1000DM003-1SB1 SCSI Disk Device (SATA)  39 °C
>   Optical Drives
>       hp PLDS DVDRW DU8AESH
>   Audio
>       Realtek High Definition Audio
> ```

Guest PC in Virtualbox:

> Operating System - Red Hat(64bit)
>
> Ram - 6GB
>
> Processors - 2
>
> Acceleration : VT-x/AMD-V, nested paging, PAE/NX, KVM paravirtualization
>
> video memory - 16MB
>
> Storage
>
> > Controller IDE : IDE secondary master - ISO file
> >
> > Controller SCSI port 0 : virtualdisk.vmdk(normal, 110GB)
>
> Audio - Disabled
>
> Netwrok - NAT

Please let me know if you had suffered from the same issue on other machines and how did you solve it.

Please also let me know if you would need more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to set up Cisco unified communication manager on VMware workstation. I still don't know what the difference is. I had much more success using Virtualbox in the past.

Feel free to share your thoughts about this issue in the future sa I will continue to follow and if someone has a solution for running it on Virtualbox please let me konw.

Thanks